# ERROR in ./node_modules/@react-pdf/pdfkit/lib/pdfkit.browser.es.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'stream' in '\node_modules\@react-pdf\pdfkit\lib'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR in ./node_modules/@react-pdf/pdfkit/lib/pdfkit.browser.es.js 2:0-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'F:\Project\node_modules@react-pdf\pdfkit\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
- install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/@react-pdf/pdfkit/lib/pdfkit.browser.es.js 4:0-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'F:\Project\node_modules@react-pdf\pdfkit\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
- install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/blob-stream/index.js 1:21-47
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'F:\Project\node_modules\blob-stream'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
- install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/esri-leaflet/src/EsriLeaflet.js 2:0-53
Should not import the named export 'version' (reexported as 'VERSION') from default-exporting module (only default export is available soon)
ERROR in ./node_modules/restructure/src/EncodeStream.js 20:11-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'F:\Project\node_modules\restructure\src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
- install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }

I have tried with the following code written in webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        fallback: {
            "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
            "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib")
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using

> "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",

webpack is used

> "webpack": "^5.64.4",
> I have tried with the above solution, but couldn't able to resolved that. Then I tried with lowering the webpack version but error is still same.